# Javascript strip Latex form of English letter variants

Tags: javascript, regex, string

How can I replace Latex characters using `{\'<1 alpha>}` pattern with corresponding English letter?

For example

> L{\'o}pez

Should change to

> Lopez

It should not affect any other character out of `{\'<1 alpha>}` pattern. It should be greedy as well since there might be several characters required to be pruned.

Comment: `string.replace(/{\\'([A-Z])}/gi, '$1');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$1` was made for this:

```
var new_string = 'L{\\\'o}pez'.replace(/\{\\['"]([A-Z])\}/gi, '$1');
```

---

The extra `\` are so we can escape the `\` and the `'`.

---

### Explained:

```
\{           Selects a {
    \\       Selects a \
    (?:      Starts a group that is not "stored"
        \'       Selects a quote
        |        OR
        \"       Selects a double quote
    )        Ends the group

    ([A-Z])  Takes one alphabetical character and stores it in a  group
\}           Selects a } to end the selection
```

**`g`:** Selects multiple times

**`i`:** Case in-sensitive. `[A-Z]` becomes: `[A-Za-z]`

Comment: Thanks to all who helped. This is the first answer which worked without error or bug

Answer (score 0):

```
{\\'([a-zA-Z])}
```

Try this.Replace by `$1`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/oF9hR9/3

```
var re = /{\\'([a-zA-Z])}/g;  
var str = 'L{\'o}pez';
var subst = '$1'; 

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```

Comment: your result "L{'o}pez"

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex like following :

```
var str = "L{\'o}pez";
var res = str.replace(/{\\'([a-zA-Z])}/g, /$1/);
```

`\S` will match a alphabetical character and the preceding `replace` function will replace the match regex `/{\'([a-zA-Z])}/g` with first group `$1` that is your character `([a-zA-Z])`.

Comment: `"L{\'o}pez";` should be `"L{\\'o}pez";`, so the regex changes.

Comment: \S will match *anything* besides whitespace

Comment: *so the regex changes* means that \ becomes \\ even in the regex

Comment: @vihan1086 Yeah its alphabetical ;)